# c# data count query

Tags: c#, list, count

I have a Treatment List and their languages. When I send a LanguageId, if my incoming list is empty, I want to return 2 LanguageIds. Everything is fine, but how do I say if data=0?

```
 public async Task<ApiResponse<IEnumerable<TreatmentResponse>>> Handle(TreatmentsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<Treatment> data = await _repo.Treatment.GetByCurrencyIdAsync(request.CurrencyId, request.languageId, request.predicate);

        if (data==null)
        {
            var b = await _repo.Language.GetByIdAsync(a => a.isDefault == true);

            var c = request.languageId == b.Id;              
        }

        var response = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TreatmentResponse>>(data);

        return new SuccessApiResponse<IEnumerable<TreatmentResponse>>(response);
    }
```

In the above scenario, data count is 0 but not looped.
[image]
[image]

Comment: `data.Count() == 0`. And import `using System.Linq;`. Check out [`IEnumerable.Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-6.0)

Comment: aaa thank you, I forgot to add Linq :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to check if your lists count is zero or not :

```
data.Count == 0
```

And as what PawZaw said, if you have an IEnumerable<> instead of a list :

```
data.Count() == 0
```

namespace you may need : `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I think if you have an `IEnumerable` you need `Count()`